# how to create triggers in sqlite3?

Tags: database, sqlite, foreign-key-relationship

i am new to this topic.
i want something like this.

i have two tables in my sqliteDatabase one is master and another is child.
Now if i delete a record from master suppose i delete a row from master where id=5, then all the records from the child table whose id = 5 deleted automatically.
I don't know how to create triggers and how to apply foreign key constraints so someone please tell me a way to do this in sqlite3 Manager of firefox.
Thanks

Comment: If you have SQLite version 3.6.19 or higher, you can do this without a trigger. See Peter Lang's answer for information on foreign keys.

Comment: Yes, 3.6.19 and higher supports foreign keys. Just do not forget right after connection to execute "pragma foreign_keys=on".

Comment: i don't know about the version where can i see the version i have firefox sqlite manager ver 0.5.11

Comment: ok i found my sqlit3 version is 3.4.0 now i have also downloaded mac version of sqlite3(Ver. 3.6.22) now how do i install this?

Comment: i have also downloaded http://www.sqlite.org/sqlite-amalgamation-3.6.22.tar.gz(A tarball containing the amalgamation  together with an configure script and makefile for building it. This is the recommended source distribution for all Unix and Unix-like platforms.) now how do i install this?

Comment: If you scroll down a little further on the downloads page, you should find Precompiled Binaries for Mac OS X. That might be easier to use if you don't have much experience installing from source.

Comment: @aardvark i have precompiled binary as well but how do i open a databse in it and how to create a new database? when i open precompiled binary is directly starts the sqlite

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need a trigger for that, your foreign key will do that if you define `ON DELETE CASCADE`:

```
CREATE TABLE child(
  id         INTEGER,
  some_info  TEXT, 
  master_id  INTEGER,
  FOREIGN KEY(master_id) REFERENCES master(id) ON DELETE CASCADE
);
```

See [documentation about foreign keys](http://www.sqlite.org/foreignkeys.html).

**EDIT:**

If you really need to do it using a trigger, have a look at [Foreing Key Triggers](http://www.sqlite.org/cvstrac/wiki?p=ForeignKeyTriggers).

Comment: can you create a trigger for this?

Comment: ok i found my sqlit3 version is 3.4.0 now i have also downloaded mac version of sqlite3(Ver. 3.6.22) now how do i install this?

Comment: i have also downloaded http://www.sqlite.org/sqlite-amalgamation-3.6.22.tar.gz(A tarball containing the amalgamation  together with an configure script and makefile for building it. This is the recommended source distribution for all Unix and Unix-like platforms.) now how do i install this?

Comment: @Rahul Vyas: I don't know how to install on Mac, but have a look at the following page: http://sqlite3.darwinports.com/. If this does not help, please ask another question about how to install it on Mac, as this is not really related to your original question.

Comment: can you create a trigger to achieve the functionality i want?

Comment: @Rahul Vyas: See the link in my updated answer. Hope that helps you to create the triggers.

Answer (score 0):

This page should help:
http://justatheory.com/computers/databases/sqlite/foreign_key_triggers.html

[This is a general trigger reference for SQLite](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtrigger.html)